React how to change two states In a way the don't collide?
Explaination of code : I have a two states toggleMenu and currentImageIndex(which changes every 2 second rerendring the image in browser) with images constant.
whenever I try to toggle menu if the same time the currentImageIndex changes the toggleMenu doesn't works sometimes works after 0.3sec
const images= useMemo(()=>[img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7],[])
const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0)
const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  setCurrentImageIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
}, 2000);

return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [images]);
windowWidth<780&&toggleMenu&&<>
            <div id="nav-menu">
              // nav menu
            </div>
<Parallax strength={450} bgImage={images[currentImageIndex]}>
    <div id="parallax">
      <Header></Header>
    </div>
  </Parallax>
</>

Can someone help that two states doesn't collide? Been working onto for 8 hours couldn't find solution please help

Can you please  show more code context.  There is another dependency windowWidth.  At least show the entire component. Also, is the timeout running even when the toggle menu is closed?  Also, why is images array defined inside the component?  One thing to note is that, per the docs, memoization is not guaranteed not to be re-caculcated.  I would use a ref, or define the variable exterior to the component.

Please provide more context.
Here is an example of working code based on what i could understand from your question:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];

export function YourComponent() {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrentImageIndex((currentImageIndex + 1) % images.length);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [currentImageIndex]);

  return (
    <div>
     <div>The current image is: {images[currentImageIndex]}</div>
     <button onClick={() => setToggleMenu((prev) => !prev)}>
       menu opener
     </button>
     {toggleMenu && <div>your menu</div>}
   </div>
 );
}

You can copy and paste that example on https://codesandbox.io/ to fiddle with it and try it out yourself
Wrapping images in useMemo is unecessary as Scott mentioned and you dont need to use setInterval, it would be simpler to use setTimeout here
Also check your parent components state, state changes higher up the tree may cause unwanted rerenders in your component
